# In SAP SCRIPT, how to add a page break or print the records in a new page

Tags: page-break, sapscript

I would like to print the records in a new page every time the contract number changes. What is the syntax for new page in the SAP SCRIPT.

Kindly let me know if you know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of SAPSCRIPT (Transaction SE71) use the control command NEW-PAGE.  (Control Commands are identified by typing /: in the format column).

Inside the Print Program (Transaction SE38) use Function Module CONTROL_FORM to call the command NEW-PAGE:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'CONTROL_FORM'
  EXPORTING
      COMMAND   = 'NEW-PAGE'
  EXCEPTIONS
      UNOPENED  = 1
      UNSTARTED = 2
      OTHERS    = 3.
```

You only need to use one of these options, depending on where you will determine if a page-break is needed.